# Twitter Bootstrap: Icon rendered differently in IE vs Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the latest twitter Bootstrap (non-modified). The below HTML produces different result in IE and Firefox:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">          
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    
            <li><p class="navbar-text">Test</p><a href:"..."> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a></li>                              
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In IE the icon (or font, the icons are fonts now days) is rendered properly after the text "test" on the same line. In Firefox the icon is rendered below the text. I would like both to render the icon on the same line. Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: what versions of IE and FF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: IE is doing it wrong.

In your `<li>`, you have 2 block elements, a `<p>` and an `<a>`.  Block elements form blocks, therefore if you want them inline, either change them to inline-block, or if the menu items are unrelated, i.e. `Test` goes somewhere different than the refresh icon, put them each in their own `<li>`, like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">          
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    
            <li><p class="navbar-text">Test</p></li>
            <li><a href:"..."> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a></li>                              
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note from comment: `<a>` tags are normally inline, but twitter bootstrap css specifically sets the `<a>` tag in the `<nav>` under `<li>` to block. `.nav>li>a {display: block;}`

Comment: I thought <a> tags were inline, not block

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy - Normally, yes. But since the OP is using bootstrap, they specifically set the <a> tag to block. `.nav>li>a {display: block;`  - from bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: oh sorry, didn't realize that. Haven't used bootstrap in a while. I'll redact my downvote asap.